# The Python Equivalent of the MATLAB function unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am aware that this question has been asked but i am not able to find the answer yet. Any help is very much appreciated

In Matlab it is written as:  `[C,ia,ic] = unique(A)`

I am interested in all output elements i.e., `C`, `ia` and `ic`

#### here is an example of what the matlab function does

```
A = [9 2 9 5];
Find the unique values of A and the index vectors ia and ic, 
such that C = A(ia) and A = C(ic).

[C, ia, ic] = unique(A)
C = 1×3

     2     5     9

ia = 3×1

     2
     4
     1

ic = 4×1

     3
     1
     3
     2
```

How can I reproduce this in python please? As mentioned, i am interested in all output elements  i.e., `C`, `ia` and `ic`

Comment: Please, provide an input example and the result you want to get.

Comment: Done. Sorry if it was not clear earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) (thanks to @SBad himself for improving the quality of the solution):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([9,2,9,5])

C, ia, ic = np.unique(A, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

print(C)
print(ia)
print(ic)
```

**output**

```
[2 5 9]
[1 3 0]
[2 0 2 1]
```

---

with list comprehension you can also get `ic` as:

```
ic = [i for j in A for i,x in enumerate(C) if x == j]
```

---

**Note**:

Remember that **MATLAB** uses 1 (one) based indexing, while **Python** uses 0 (zero) based indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In a context of a dataframe, how would you  extend the code above?  for instance,  `C, ia = np.unique(DF[['A', 'B', 'C']],  return_index=True)`    when i tried it i got an error  ...any further is more than welcome thank you

Comment: @SBad I think you should ask a new question with an example of the dataframe. Here we would mess things up.

Comment: C, ia, ic = np.unique(A, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)